# Predix Timeseries Service still can be query with status 200 after be deleted

Tags: time-series, cloud-foundry, predix

I have a Timeseries service which was created in the past. Then it was deleted by someone. I can't see it with "cf s". But when I query it with a Post request, it still return status 200. I'm not really clear this. Any ideas are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to query a service instance after it's been deleted. Are you using the Predix Zone ID for the old deleted service instance? Or a new instance? I'm thinking you must be querying a different service instance.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I used the old Predix_Zone_ID. That's why I'm wondering that after deleting the TS Service, the service is still be there for a while?!